# AngularJS String with newlines, shown without breaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the database I'm saving input from a textarea, where you can add breaks. But how to show them in a Angular view? For PHP this is `nl2br()`.

Like `<div>{{ item.foobar }}</div>`, with breaks shown that are saved like that in the database.

Comment: This could also be used to ask/answer the same question about with line breaks(\n) instead of just html breaks(<br>).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Binding an HTML seems a bit unsafe. The directive suggested by CuriousGuy has a bit of extra engineering to correctly escape the HTML.

I find it easier to use a styling rule `white-space: pre-line`.

Example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/10/).

See also:

- [Mozilla Developer Network documentation for `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
- [Internet Explorer documentation for `white-space`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [W3 documentation for `white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space)

Comment: pre-line! you're THE boss.

Comment: What is the browser compatibility on this one?

Comment: Super ! very nice, easy and clean.

Comment: this is the correct answer, would be better than including html code!

Comment: Using the style `white-space: pre-line` is the simplest solution, i think.

Answer (score 12):

Best solution:

```
<div class="multi_lines_text">{{ item.foobar }}</div>

<style>
.multi_lines_text { white-space: pre-line; }
</style>
```

ng-bind-html - it's not safe way and display error in console.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add line breaks only and all the rest text to show as is you can use the following filter:

```
app.filter('nl2br', function() {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    return function(input) {
        if (!input) return input;
        var lines = input.split('\n');

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            span.innerText = lines[i];
            span.textContent = lines[i];  //for Firefox
            lines[i] = span.innerHTML;
        }
        return lines.join('<br />');
    }
});
```

then use it in view like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="someVar | nl2br"></div>
```

In this case the only HTML tag that is present in the result string is `<br />`. All other tags will be escaped.
And don't forget to load `ngSanitize` module (`angular-sanitize.js` script).

The full working example you can find [**on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/).

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just do something like `return (input || '').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');`?

Comment: @CWSpear The idea is to make `someVar` be shown as simple text, without rendering HTML tags (except `<br>` on the line breaks). You may compare these two jsFiddles: [first](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/6/) and [second](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/4/)

Comment: @CWSpear my appologies, here are corrected jsFiddles: [first](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/7/) and [second](http://jsfiddle.net/mqcpe/8/). (StackOverflow doesn't allow editing comments after 5 mins since they were posted)

Answer (score 1):

Googling angularjs nl2br yielded this result:

[AngularJS - Remove \n from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235842/angularjs-remove-n-from-data)

Namely the last answer which demonstrates how to replace new lines with `<br />` using a filter. Combine that with ng-bind-html, as the unsafe version might not be currently available. You should probably convert the line breaks to `<br />` when inserting them to database(makes more sense to me).