# How to wrap text of primeng checkbox label?

Tags: angular, checkbox, styles, primeng

I'm having troubles wrapping the text of the checkbox label. I read the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) and [how to use styleClass properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350302/primeng-how-to-use-styleclass) and I'm still not able to make any change.

I'm not using `:host /deep/` selector because I'm not using the styleUrl of the @Component, instead one loaded and adapted for Firefox.

`ui-chkbox-label` is not used anywhere in the project besides primeng lib and me in the below code.

html:

```
<p-checkbox styleClass="chBoxOne" labelStyleClass="lblChBoxOne" [(ngModel)]="allowParticipation"  
binary="true" 
label="This very very long sentence needs to be wrapped to make it fit"     
(click)="onClickAllowParticipation()"></p-checkbox>
```

css attempts:

```
/*labelStyleClass + Container*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

/*labelStyleClass + Label element*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox-label{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

/*labelStyleClass + Container element + Label element*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*labelStyleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a checked state.*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-active{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*labelStyleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a focused state .*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-focus{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*labelStyleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a disabled state.*/
.lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-disabled{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

 /*styleClass + Container*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}    

/*styleClass + Label element*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox-label{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

/*styleClass + Container element + Label element*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*styleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a checked state.*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-active{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*styleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a focused state .*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-focus{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
/*styleClass + Container element + Label element + Label element of a disabled state.*/
.chBoxOne.ui-chkbox.ui-chkbox-label.ui-label-disabled{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Result:

[image: Wrap text primeng checkbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found is:

- Add the label text as a property in the typescript file the checkbox belongs to, and wrap the text where is needed:

  ```
  export class xxxx {
  ...
  chBoxOneLabel = "This very very long sentence needs to be wrapped to make \n
  it fit";
  ...
  }
  ```
- Add the `white-space` property to the checkbox label in the CSS file:

  ```
  .lblChBoxOne.ui-chkbox-label{
      white-space: pre-wrap
  }
  ```
- Replace the label text in the tag for the component property:

  ```
  <p-checkbox ... label={{chBoxOneLabel}}></p-checkbox>
  ```

Sources:

[Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

[multi-line text will not do line break in view](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7781)

[AngularJS String with newlines, shown without breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813857/angularjs-string-with-newlines-shown-without-breaks)